# Optimal way to use null conditional operators in boolean expressions

Tags: c#

You are writing a boolean expression that might look like this:

`team.Category == "A Team" && team?.Manager?.IsVietnamVet`

```
public class Manager
{
    public bool IsVietnamVet { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
}
```

...and you get an error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'

What is the optimal/cleanest way to handle it?

1. `team.Category == "A Team" && (team?.Manager?.IsVietnamVet ?? false)`

   *Is that really readable?*
2. `team.Category == "A Team" && (team?.Manager?.IsVietnamVet).GetValueOrDefault()`

   *It may not work in LINQ-to-Entities...*
3. `team.Category == "A Team" && team?.Manager?.IsVietnamVet == true`

   *Would you really write `if (condition == true)` without any hesitation?*

Are there any other options? Is it ultimately better to write:

4. `team.Category == "A Team" && team.Manager != null && team.Manager.IsVietnamVet`

Comment: if(!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(team.Manager) && condition)) ...

Comment: @StevieV Manager property is not a string, sorry if that was not clear before

Comment: Ok well category is right? EDIT: Now I've confused myself... because the question was edited?

Comment: @StevieV it was ment to be like this right from the start ;)

Comment: The boolean comparison with a string makes no sense.  What is "A Team" supposed to represent?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Why? It is just an example, you could have a bool property there instead. Why do you care about the data when the question is clearly about the syntax.

Comment: Looking at the code more carefully, the null conditional part should be `team.Manager?.IsVietnamVet`, i.e. no null conditional after `team`, since already can't be `null`.

Comment: _"Would you really write if (condition == true) without any hesitation?"_ For a normal boolean, no, since it's superfluous. However, for a **nullable boolean**, this is relevant. `nullableBool == true` is basically testing for `nullableBool != false && nullableBool != null` (and it's this second part that makes it **useful** and therefore not superfluous)

Comment: Using multiple null conditional operators will far away from readable code.

Comment: I started to use `nullableBool == true` if I don't create a wrapper. It is readable because you normally don't write `== true` when using regular boolean as @Flater mentions, so it suggests that the variable is nullable. Aditionally, it improves LINQ readability because you don't use multiple null conditions as @Fabio mentions.

Comment: VB.net used to be so behind but these days it's wonderful.  Mixing nullable/non-nullable in a shortcut Boolean works fine.  I was converting it to C# for a project when I ran across the same problem.

If Team.Category = "A Team" AndAlso team?.Manager?.IsVietnamVet Then....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case, it might be wise to follow the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) i.e.

```
public class Team
{
    public bool IsManagerVietnamVet => Manager?.IsVietnamVet ?? false;
}
```

More generally, if a boolean expression is complex or ugly then there's nothing to say you couldn't divide it (or part of it) into a separate statement:

```
bool isVietnamVet = Manager?.IsVietnamVet ?? false;

if (team.Category == "A Team" && isVietnamVet)
```

When stepping through code in the debugger, it's often nicer to have elaborate conditions packaged up into a single `bool` just to save a little bit of mouseover-hovering; in fact, it might just be nicer to put the whole thing in a `bool` variable.

```
bool isVietnamVetAndCategoryA = (team.Category == "A Team"
    && Manager?.IsVietnamVet ?? false);

if (isVietnamVetAndCategoryA)
```

or with LINQ:

```
var wibble = from flight in airport
             from passenger in flight.manifest
             let isOnPlane = 
                 (flight.FinishedBoarding && passenger.Flight == flight.FlightNumber)
             where !isOnPlane
             select passenger;
```

Comment: I think I am mostly leaning towards such a solution.

Comment: New C# syntax to save a few lines: public bool IsManagerVietnamVet =>  (team.Category=="") && (team.Manager?.IsVietnamVet?? false);

Comment: Just keep in mind that long `a && b && c &&...`are executed sequentially, and the next one is not even executed if the previous one is `false`. So people usually put fastest at the beginning. Keep that in mind when moving stuff into a separate bool-var

Comment: @jitbit It's more about maintainability.  Micro-optimisations such as the one you mention are generally unnecessary - it's not worth worrying about unless performance is identified as an issue and profiling shows that making changes like that would have any noticeable impact.

Comment: @BenCottrell I would call it a "micro" optimization if the `IsManagerVietnamVet` property goes to check in a database ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think option 3 (i.e. `== true`) is the cleanest way to test that a `bool?` is `true`, because it's very clear about what it does.

In most code `x == true` doesn't make sense, because it's the same as `x`, but that does not apply here, so I think `== true` wouldn't be very confusing.

Comment: I think this would definitely be the way to go if we wanted to use the null conditional operator, because it is also linq safe. The question is whether the readability is good. From my point of view, the choice is between opt 3 and opt 4 and I would choose 4 over 3 for the readability reason, also the programmer's intention seems a bit clearer. I have marked Ben Cottrell's answer as correct because I like that approach a bit more. If I could mark two answers, I would.

Comment: @Santhos -- re "the programmer's intention seems a bit clearer". IMHO, this is a case where the first time a programmer sees `a?.b == true` they will be confused, but once they grasp what it is doing, it becomes a very readable idiom, much nicer than having to test `!= null` in the middle of a complex expression.  Same for `a?.b ?? false`, which seems to have gained traction as the most popular solution, because it matches what you would type if you were dealing with a type *other* than boolean [though I don't like it for boolean; for me, it doesn't read as naturally; I prefer `== true`].

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Ben Cottrell's answer, the "Null Object" pattern can help you further.

Instead of returning a `null` team/manager, extract `ITeam` and `IManager` interfaces and return meaningful alternative implementations:

```
public class NoManager : IManager
{
    public bool IsVietnamVet => false;
}

public class NoTeam : ITeam
{
    public bool ManagedByVietnamVet => false;

    public IManager Manager => new NoManager();
}
```

Then all of a sudden you can do `team.ManagedByVietnamVet` safely.

This of course relies on the upstream provider of `team` to be null-safe - but that can be ensured with appropriate testing.

Answer (score -4):

I wrote a simple class you could use:

```
 public class MyBool 
    {
        public bool? Value { get; set; }

        public MyBool(bool b)
        {
            Value = b;
        }

        public MyBool(bool? b)
        {
            Value = b;
        }

        public static implicit operator bool(MyBool m)
        {
            return m?.Value ?? false;
        }

        public static implicit operator bool?(MyBool m)
        {
            return m?.Value;
        }

        public static implicit operator MyBool(bool m)
        {
            return new MyBool(m);
        }

        public static implicit operator MyBool(bool? m)
        {
            return new MyBool(m);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If reliable to use a custom type, of course.
You can compare `MyBool` with both `bool` and `Nullable<bool>`.

Comment: This site is for questions about software design rather than how to get specific pieces of code to work, so if you believe this is the best solution then your answer should focus on *why* you believe a class like this is the best possible solution, not the exact code needed to implement it.